# plot rownames based on condition in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10), col = rbinom(10, size=1,prob= 0.5))
rownames(df) <- letters[1:10]

> head(df)
          v1 col
a -0.1806868   1
b  0.6934783   0
c -0.4658297   1
d  1.6760829   0
e -0.8475840   0
f -1.3499387   1
```

I plot it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = v1, y=rownames(df), group = col, color= col)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Now I want to show only the rownames on the y-axis where `col` == 1.
The other names should not be displayed (but the points should be)

To add some context, I have a plot with many overlapping variable names on the y-axis, but I only want to display the names of the ones outside the dashed line[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scale_y_discrete`:

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10), col = rbinom(10, size=1,prob= 0.5))
rownames(df) <- letters[1:10]

library(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = v1, y = rownames(df), group = col, color = col)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_discrete(
        limits = rownames(df),
        labels = ifelse(df$col == 1, rownames(df), ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to add to the answer given by @MauritsEvers, I just had the idea that for your plot it might be desirable to have fewer horizontal lines that guide your eye.

We can use the `breaks` argument  in `scale_y_discrete` for that.

```
set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10), col = rbinom(10, size=1,prob= 0.5))
rownames(df) <- letters[1:10]

axis_labels <- which(df$col == 1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = v1, y=rownames(df), group = col, color= col)) +
 geom_point() +
 scale_y_discrete(breaks = rownames(df)[axis_labels])
```

[image]